# How to send back the boxShadow from gradient?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to make a container with gradient color and shadow. But shadow is always front from the gradient.
How can i fix this?

```
Container(
                  width: 184,
                  height: 127,
                  decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                    gradient: new LinearGradient(colors: [
                      Color(0xFFFFC1CD).withOpacity(0.6),
                      Color(0XFFA5E8FF).withOpacity(0.6),
                    ], stops: [
                      0.0,
                      1.0
                    ], begin: FractionalOffset.topCenter, end: FractionalOffset.bottomCenter, tileMode: TileMode.repeated),
                    boxShadow: [
                      BoxShadow(
                        color: Color(0xFF797D7F),
                        offset: Offset(0, 10),
                        blurRadius: 10,
                        spreadRadius: 0.5,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  child: Material(
                    color: Colors.transparent,
                    child: InkWell(
                        onTap: () {},
                        child: Center(
                          child: Text("Hi"),
                        )),
                  ),
                ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a container with box shadow and make the one with the gradient a child of it